# Proof of f(n) + ο(f(n)) = Θ(f(n))

Tags: algorithm

Can you please help me prove this? I am trying to set o(f(n))= g(n) and then try to solve the equation
f(n) + g(n) = Θ(f(n)) but I don't know if it is the correct way, and if it is I don't know how to continue my solution. Thank you

Comment: This is not a conrete programming problem, please try cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: That's the correct-ish first step, but there are a few layers of quantification here, and you need to handle them very carefully. math.SE or cs.SE will be able to help you.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139048/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67139954/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the functions are non-negative (otherwise you need to adjust the below proof and definitions to cope with signs).

Suppose g(n) = o(f(n)). That means that for all c>0, there's an N such that n>N implies g(n) < cf(n). So in particular, there's an N such that n>N implies g(n) < f(n) (ie: pick c=1 in the definition).

We also have from the assumption that the functions are non-negative that f(n) <= f(n) + g(n).

Then we have for n>N, f(n) <= f(n) + g(n) < 2f(n) for all n>N. Thus f(n) + g(n) = Theta(f(n)).